# editing 2d lists based on contents in the 2d list

Tags: python

For a homework assignment I have to make a text-based Conway's game of life in python. The rules for it are this.

---

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies

Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.

Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies.

Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell.

---

I put the board in a 2d list and i'm having trouble finding out how to loop over each individual element in the list(each cell in the game, dead or alive, '0' or 'X') and check conditions based on the cells around it.

An example of a starting board would be

```
00000
00000
000X0
000X0
000X0
```

To start out I am now trying to loop over each element, and check if cell to the right of the current cell is an X or not.

This is the code I made to try and do this. The function next iteration is supposed to return the board with what the next iteration of conway's game of life would be, but for now to figure things out I just want to get it to check the cell to the right of it and change the current cell to an X if the one to the right of it is.

```
def nextIteration(board):
    newBoardTemp = board[:]
    newBoard = [board[:] for board in newBoardTemp]
    column = 0
    for row in newBoard:
        column = 0
        for item in range(len(row)):
             column += 1
             item2 = row[column + 1]
             if item == item2:
                 board[item][column] = 'X'


def printBoard(board):
   for row in board:
       for item in row:
           print(item, end="")
       print()


def main():
    rows = input("Please enter number of rows: ")
    columns = input("Please enter number of columns: ")
    print()
    cellRow = 0
    cellRows = []
    cellColumns = []
    total = 0
    #the cellRow and cellColumn will contain all of the inputted rows           
    #and columns connected by the index value                                   
    while cellRow != "q":
        cellRow = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exi\
t): ")
        if cellRow != "q":
                cellColumn = input("Please enter a column for that cell: ")
                cellRows.append(cellRow)
                cellColumns.append(cellColumn)
                total = total + 1
                print()
        else:
            print()
    board = []
    #boardTemp will hold a list that contains one row of the entire board       
    boardTemp = []
    for i in range(int(rows)):
        boardTemp.append("0")
    for i in range(int(columns)):
        board.append(boardTemp[:])
    for i in range(total):
        temp = i
        board[int(cellRows[temp - 1])][int(cellColumns[temp - 1])] = "X"
    iterations = input("How many iterations should I run? ")
 print()
    print("Starting Board:")
    print()
    printBoard(board)
    for i in range(int(iterations)):
        iterationNumber = 1
        nextIteration(board)
        print("Iteration", iterationNumber,":")
        printBoard(board)

main()
```

This is the error I get with the starting board that I showed earlier.

```
File "hw7.py", line 9, in nextIteration
    item2 = row[column + 1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in range(len(row)):
    column += 1
    item2 = row[column + 1]
    if item == item2:
        board[item][column] = 'X'
```

In fourth iteration of this loop you set item2 to row[5], which is out of range. 
If you want to compare two adjacent cells, you should increment column later (in first iteration item == row[0] and item2 == row[2]).
You should also stop a loop earlier. 
The following should help with your error:

```
for item in range(len(row) - 1):
    item2 = row[column + 1]
    if item == item2:
        board[item][column] = 'X'
    column += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the edges?  One possibility is to treat the surface as a torus, aka donut... If that's OK with you, please follow me

```
nr = 5 ;  nc = 4
# here I define a List Of Lists with content unrelated to Conway's Life
# just to have an easy to follow example
lol = [["%d"%(r*10+c+11,) for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]
print(lol)
# [['11', '12', '13', '14'],
#  ['21', '22', '23', '24'],
#  ['31', '32', '33', '34'],
#  ['41', '42', '43', '44'],
#  ['51', '52', '53', '54']]

# now, we build an AUGmented List Of Lists, prepending each row with
# its last element and appending the last one, prepending the first
# augmented row with the last row and appending the first to the last
aug_lol = [[lol[r%nr][c%nc] for c in range(-1,nc+1)] for r in range(-1,nr+1)]
print(aug_lol)
# [['54', '51', '52', '53', '54', '51'],
#  ['14', '11', '12', '13', '14', '11'],
#  ['24', '21', '22', '23', '24', '21'],
#  ['34', '31', '32', '33', '34', '31'],
#  ['44', '41', '42', '43', '44', '41'],
#  ['54', '51', '52', '53', '54', '51'],
#  ['14', '11', '12', '13', '14', '11']]
```

Using the `aug_lol` list of lists you can query the neighbours of element `11` (or whatever) in the most natural way,

```
def neighborhood(alol, r, c):
    return [alol[nr][nc] for nc in range(c,c+3)
                         for nr in range(r,r+3)
                         if (nr!=(r+1) or nc!=(c+1))]
```

To count the living neighbours,

```
ln = sum(c=="X" for c in neighborhood(...))
```

To print the board, the following is more efficient

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(ch for ch in r) for r in board))
```